# Linux Mint update GPG error

Tags: linux, apt-get, gnupg, linux-mint

I search a lot about this problem, but all the solutions I found did not solve my problem.
I installed Linux Mint 17 with mate desktop in a virtual machine. After the installation, I wanted to update the packages but after running

```
apt-get update
```

I get the following error:

```
E: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 2
```

The solutions I found in https://askubuntu.com/questions/104213/gpg-invalid-signature did not solve it.

I think the problem is that the computer is behind a proxy. I tried all the different proxy settings, but the error still exists.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself :)

first you have to comment out the repositories, that are not working (trusty-main, trusty-updates and trusty-security)

then you can update the remaining packages

After that you have to find a mirror that is working for the above repositories (the german gwdg server worked for me)

After you added the corresponding repositories, you can update the remaining programs.

apparently it is important to first update the other packages before you update the ones from the above repositories.